# How to show all combinations of IP address that can be created from a string of numbers?

Tags: java, data-structures

I need to format the input string into IP address format, so I have the following code;however,the numbers are fixed and I am not sure how to generated different values for a single input.

Other constraints would be to make sure no group of numbers is more than 255, but in this case I just want to put them in four separate groups and each group must have 1 to 3 members.

**Vimal's question:** From provided string 19216801, I think you cant identify exact ip. It can be 192.168.0.1 or 19.216.80.1 or any other combination.

**Answer:** I am not looking for any specific IP I just need to show all the possible combinations.

**Sample formats**

Some of the combinations would be as following

```
   Expected result | number of input characters

   1.1.1.1             4 
     ....
   1.1.1.2             5
   1.1.2.1  
   1.2.1.1  
   2.1.1.1 
     ....       
   1.1.1.3             6
   1.1.3.1  
   1.3.1.1   
   3.1.1.1  
     ....
   2.2.2.1             7
   2.2.1.2 
     ....
   2.2.2.2             8
   3.2.2.1 
   1.2.2.3 
     ....
   2.2.2.3             9 
   3.3.2.1 
   1.2.3.3 
     ....
   3.3.3.1             10
   3.3.1.3  
   3.1.3.3
   1.3.3.3 
     ....
   3.3.3.2             11
   3.3.2.3 
   3.2.3.3 
     ....
   3.3.3.3             12
```

**Code**

```
String number = "19216801";
if (number.length() == 4) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(number)
            .insert(1, ".")
            .insert(1, ".")
            .insert(1, ".")
            .insert(1, ".");
    String output = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(output);
}
 if (number.length() == 8) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(number)
            .insert(2, ".")
            .insert(2, ".")
            .insert(2, ".")
            .insert(2, ".");
    String output = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(output);
}
  if (number.length() == 12) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(number)
            .insert(3, ".")
            .insert(3, ".")
            .insert(3, ".")
            .insert(3, ".");
    String output = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Comment: From provided string 19216801, I think you cant identify exact ip. It can be 192.168.0.1 or 19.216.80.1 or any other combination.

Comment: An IP address is 4 bytes. An `int` is also 4 bytes. Are you sure that number `19216801` is not the `int` value of the IP address? It would then result in `0x12539a1` which is `1.37.57.161`.

Comment: I agree with @VimalBera, I don't see how you can know wich actual IP address is represented by such a String, unless all your strings are 12-character long (which is not the case yet), with padding 0s for each number.

Comment: @VimalBera I need to show all the combinations

Comment: @icza it is much simpler, I just need to show all the IP addresses that I can create from the string such as what Vimal explained.

Comment: @Joffrey question is updated with an answer to vimal.

Comment: @Jack Oh, ok. I had misunderstood. Now it makes sense.

Comment: the follow-up question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886289/follow-uphow-to-show-all-combinations-of-ip-address-that-can-be-created-from-a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rephrase task in next way.

1. imagine that ip part can have zero digit so `...` is valid
2. then we have number.length() - 3 elements and need to put 3 dot in any position
3. let `a`, `b`, `c` be length of part
4. first part can be any length `for(int a = 0; a < l; a++)`
5. second one must be shorter `for(int b = 0; b < l-a; b++)`
6. same with third, total length must be l. so l>=a+b+c is constraint. c

   put points in it places.

   first poin just after first part (don't forget tat at first step we cut one digit from each part).

   second is after first part, first dot and second part ((a +1) + 1 + (b+1))

   third one the same. skip first part (a+1), dot (+1), second part (+b+1), second dot (+1) and third part (c+1) = a+b+c+5

   ```
   String number = "19216801";
   int l = number.length() - 3;
   for(int a = 0; a < l; a++) {
       for(int b = 0; b < l-a; b++){
           for(int c = 0; c <l-a-b; c++){
               StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(number);
               sb.insert(a+1, ".");
               sb.insert(a+b+3, ".");
               sb.insert(a+b+c+5, ".");
               System.out.println(sb);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

It pretty difficult to explain, most of code come from background of my mind i just write it.

Comment: thanks, how did you come up with this code? would you explain the code as there is no comment in it.

Comment: @Jack It is basically inserting 3 dots at every possible position. When `a` is too far on the right, and there's no room for other dots, it stops because other loops are limited by the position of `a`.

Comment: It can possible produce incorrect ip e.g. `1.9.2.16801` easeest way to handle it valdate that part no longer then 3. Also it can produce ip like this `1.216.8.01` this problrm not so easy to solve. and last `1.921.680.1` is possible too.

Comment: @Jack Just re-read my explaination. it's horrible, let me know if you dont understend some steps. i'll try to fix them

Comment: +1, and feel free to incorporate my regex into the answer and I'll delete mine.

Comment: @Bathsheba sorry but I personally hate regexp :)

Comment: But you need to validate the address elements somehow.

Comment: @Bathsheba I leave this task to Jack :)

Comment: thanks, the follow-up question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886289/follow-uphow-to-show-all-combinations-of-ip-address-that-can-be-created-from-a

Comment: @Jack did you try to aaply Bathsheba's solutin?

Answer (score 1):

Without further information you have to rely on conjecture to form an IP address from a variable length string.

You should disallow that and ensure that your string is 12 characters long.

Once you've formed a candidate IP address though, you can validate it using the following *regular expression* (using `String.matches`)

```
\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.
  (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.
  (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.
  (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class IPAddress {
    static Queue<List<StringBuilder>> queue=new LinkedList<List<StringBuilder>>();
    static int count =0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try(Scanner reader=new Scanner(System.in)){
            String str=reader.nextLine();
            if(init(str)==-1)
                System.out.println("IPAddress cannot be formed");
            ipAddress();
        }


    }

    private static void ipAddress() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int noOfGroups=4;


        int group=noOfGroups-1;
        int countInOneLevel=1, childCount=0;
            while(!queue.isEmpty() && countInOneLevel>0 && group>0){
                List<StringBuilder> list=queue.poll();
                countInOneLevel--;
                StringBuilder currentGroup=list.get(group);
                StringBuilder prevGroup=list.get(group-1);
                while(currentGroup.length()>1){
                    prevGroup.append(currentGroup.charAt(0));
                    currentGroup=currentGroup.deleteCharAt(0);
                    if(makeIPAdress(list, group)==1 ){
                        childCount++;
                    }

                }
                if(countInOneLevel==0){//current level complete
                    countInOneLevel=childCount;
                    group--;
                    childCount=0;
                }


            }


        System.out.println("No. of possible IPAddress: "+count);

}

    private static int init(String str) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int length=str.length();
        if(length<4 || length>12)
            return -1;
        StringBuilder strgroup[]= new StringBuilder[4];
        int groups=4;
        for(int i=0;i<groups-1;i++){
            strgroup[i]=new StringBuilder(str.substring(i,i+1));
        }
        strgroup[groups-1]=new StringBuilder(str.substring(3,length));
        List<StringBuilder> list=new ArrayList<StringBuilder>();
        for(int i=0;i<groups;i++){
            list.add(strgroup[i]);
        }
        return makeIPAdress(list,groups-1);

    }

    private static int makeIPAdress(List<StringBuilder> list, int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(isValidIPAdress(list)){
            List<StringBuilder> list1=new ArrayList<StringBuilder>();
            for(int k=0;k<4;k++){
                StringBuilder s=new StringBuilder(list.get(k).toString());
                list1.add(s);
            }
            queue.offer(list1);
            display(list);
            count++;
            return 1;
        }
        for(int group=i;group>0;group--){
            StringBuilder currentGroup=list.get(group);
            StringBuilder prevGroup=list.get(group-1);
            int num=Integer.parseInt(currentGroup.toString());
            while(num<0|| num>255){
                prevGroup.append(currentGroup.charAt(0));
                currentGroup=currentGroup.deleteCharAt(0);
                num=Integer.parseInt(currentGroup.toString());
            }

        }
        StringBuilder firstGroup=list.get(0);
        int num=Integer.parseInt(firstGroup.toString());
        if(num>=0 && num<=255){
            List<StringBuilder> list1=new ArrayList<StringBuilder>();
            for(int k=0;k<4;k++){
                StringBuilder s=new StringBuilder(list.get(k).toString());
                list1.add(s);
            }

            queue.offer(list1);
            display(list);
            count++;
            return 1;
        }
        return -1;

    }

    private static boolean isValidIPAdress(List<StringBuilder> list) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(int group=0;group<4;group++){
            int num=Integer.parseInt(list.get(group).toString());
            if(num<0 || num>255)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static void display(List<StringBuilder> list) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Iterator<StringBuilder> i=list.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext()){
            StringBuilder s=i.next();
            if(!i.hasNext())
                System.out.print(s);
            else
                System.out.print(s+".");

        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}

Sample Input:
2252555

Sample Output:
2.25.25.55
2.25.255.5
2.252.55.5
225.25.5.5
22.52.55.5
225.2.55.5
No. of possible IPAddress: 6
```

Comment: So for a give string the above program displays all possible IPV4 addresses that can be formed, eg. Sample Input:
2252555

Sample Output:
2.25.25.55
2.25.255.5
2.252.55.5
225.25.5.5
22.52.55.5
225.2.55.5
No. of possible IPAddress: 6

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.println(findIPs("1234567", 3));
}

public static List<String> findIPs(String s,int dots){

    List<String> ips = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i =1 ;i<=3 && i < s.length(); i++){

        String cip = s.substring(0,i);

        if(Integer.parseInt(cip) < 256){
            if(dots == 1){
                if( Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i)) < 256) {
                    ips.add(cip + "." + s.substring(i));
                }
            }else {
                for (String ip : findIPs(s.substring(i), dots - 1)) {
                    ips.add(cip + "." + ip);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return ips;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to resolve the wrong ips issue of  one of the above solutions

```
    private static List<String> ips = new ArrayList<>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Date d = new Date();
        System.out.println(posIps("19216801"));
        System.out.println(new Date().getTime() - d.getTime());

    }

    private static List<String> posIps(String number) {
        int l = number.length() - 3;
        for (int a = 0; a < 3 && a < l; a++) {
            for (int b = 0; b < 3 && b < l - a; b++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < 3 && c < l - a - b; c++) {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(number);
                    if (Integer.parseInt(sb.substring(0, a + 1 )) < 256
                            && Integer.parseInt(sb.substring(a + 1, a + b + 2)) < 256
                            && Integer.parseInt(sb.substring(a + b + 2, a + b + c + 3)) < 256
                            && Integer.parseInt(sb.substring(a + b + c + 3)) < 256) {
                        sb.insert(a + 1, ".");
                        sb.insert(a + b + 3, ".");
                        sb.insert(a + b + c + 5, ".");
                        ips.add(sb.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return ips;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine, check it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "121212111";
    for (String ipAddress : generatePossibleIpAddresses(input, 3)) {
        System.out.println(ipAddress);
    }
}

public static ArrayList<String> generatePossibleIpAddresses(String ipAddress, int dot) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (ipAddress == null || ipAddress.length() == 0) {
        return list;
    }

    if (dot == 0) {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(ipAddress);
        if (i < 256) {
            list.add(ipAddress);
        }
        return list;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(ipAddress.substring(0, i));
        if (num < 256) {
            for (String str : generatePossibleIpAddresses(ipAddress.substring(i), dot - 1)) {
                list.add(num + "." + str);
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String getValidIp(List<Integer> combination, String ip) {
    int from = 0;
    int to = 0;
    String finalIp = "";
    for (int digit : combination) {
        to += digit;
        String ipPart = ip.substring(from, to);
        if (!isValidIp(ipPart)) {
            return null;
        }
        finalIp += ipPart + ".";
        from = to;
    }
    return finalIp.replaceAll(".$", "");
}

public static List<List<Integer>> getOptions(String ip) {
    List<Integer> baseOption = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
    List<List<Integer>> options = new ArrayList<>();
    baseOption.forEach(i -> {
        baseOption.forEach(i2 -> {
            baseOption.forEach(i3 -> {
                baseOption.forEach(i4 -> {
                    if (isRelevantOption(ip, i + i2 + i3 + i4)) {
                        options.add(Arrays.asList(i, i2, i3, i4));
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
    return options;
}

private static boolean isRelevantOption(String ip, int sum) {
    return ip.length() == sum;
}

private static boolean isValidIp(String ip) {
    return Integer.parseInt(ip) < 256;
}

public static List<String> GetAllValidIpAddress(String ip) {
    if (ip.length() > 12) {
        System.out.println("IP is not valid");
    }
    List<List<Integer>> options = getOptions(ip);
    return options.stream().map(c -> getValidIp(c, ip)).filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    GetAllValidIpAddress("2562547").forEach(ip -> System.out.println(ip));
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.