# Follow-up:How to show all combinations of IP address that can be created from a string of numbers?

Tags: java, data-structures

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884250/how-to-show-all-combinations-of-ip-address-that-can-be-created-from-a-string-of).

I need to format the input string into IP address format, so I have the following code; however, the problem is that it is providing all the combinations but I need to find those that each of their groups in not more than 255.

Question: From provided string 19216801, I think you can't identify exact ip. It can be 192.168.0.1 or 19.216.80.1 or any other combination?

Answer: I am not looking for any specific IP I just need to show all the possible combinations that their groups are not more than 255.

**Code**

```
String number = "19216801";
int l = number.length() - 3;
for(int a = 0; a < l; a++) {
    for(int b = 0; b < l-a; b++){
        for(int c = 0; c <l-a-b; c++){
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(number);
            sb.insert(a+1, ".");
            sb.insert(a+b+3, ".");
            sb.insert(a+b+c+5, ".");
            System.out.println(sb);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What would you expect from "192168000001" - or is that illegal? I ask because one of the results from [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25887281/823393) is "192.16.8.1" which may be incorrect.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon 192168000001 is wrong the maximum numbers should be 3 numbers in each group, we have 4 groups of 3 so maximum length of string is 12.

Comment: That string has 12 digits doesn't it?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I made a mistake sorry, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

I'm suggest next method to validate part (assuming that input string valid)

```
private static boolean isValid(String substring) {
    if(substring.startsWith("0")){
        return false;
    }
    try {
        return (valueOf(substring) <= 255);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

call it at beginning of most inner loop.  like this

```
if (!isValid(number.substring(0, a + 1))) continue;
if (!isValid(number.substring(a + 1, a + b + 2))) continue;
if (!isValid(number.substring(a + b + 2, a + b + c + 3))) continue;
if (!isValid(number.substring(a + b + c + 3))) continue;
```

Comment: I am a bit confused where should I call it?

Answer (score 0):

Right before printing, try:

```
boolean valid = true;
String[] segments = sb.toString().split(".");
for(String seg: segments)
{
    if(Integer.parseInt(seg) > 255)
    {
        valid = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

and then

```
if(valid)
    print ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Within your code you could use:

```
for(int c = 0; c <l-a-b; c++){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(number);
    sb.insert(a+1, ".");
    sb.insert(a+b+3, ".");
    sb.insert(a+b+c+5, ".");

    String[] parts = sb.toString().split('.');
    boolean valid = true;
    for(String part: parts)
        if(Integer.parseInt(part) > 255)
            valid = false;

    if(valid)
        System.out.println(sb);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
    String number = "19216801";
    // Digits in 1st number.
    for (int a = 1; a <= 3; a++) {
        for (int b = 1; b <= 3; b++) {
            for (int c = 1; c <= 3; c++) {
                for (int d = 1; d <= 3; d++) {
                    if (a + b + c + d == number.length()) {
                        int n0 = Integer.parseInt(number.substring(0, a));
                        int n1 = Integer.parseInt(number.substring(a, a + b));
                        int n2 = Integer.parseInt(number.substring(a + b, a + b + c));
                        int n3 = Integer.parseInt(number.substring(a + b + c, a + b + c + d));
                        if (n0 >= 0 && n0 <= 255
                                && n1 >= 0 && n1 <= 255
                                && n2 >= 0 && n2 <= 255
                                && n3 >= 0 && n3 <= 255) {
                            System.out.println(n0 + "." + n1 + "." + n2 + "." + n3 + ".");

                        }
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

prints

```
1.92.168.1.
19.2.168.1.
19.21.68.1.
19.216.8.1.
19.216.80.1.
192.1.68.1.
192.16.8.1.
192.16.80.1.
192.168.0.1.
```

Alternatively - if leading zeros indicates an invalid:

```
public void test() {
    String number = "19216801";
    // Digits in 1st number.
    for (int a = 1; a <= 3; a++) {
        for (int b = 1; b <= 3; b++) {
            for (int c = 1; c <= 3; c++) {
                for (int d = 1; d <= 3; d++) {
                    if (a + b + c + d == number.length()) {
                        String s0 = number.substring(0, a);
                        String s1 = number.substring(a, a + b);
                        String s2 = number.substring(a + b, a + b + c);
                        String s3 = number.substring(a + b + c, a + b + c + d);
                        if (good(s0) && good(s1) && good(s2) && good(s3)) {
                            int n0 = Integer.parseInt(s0);
                            int n1 = Integer.parseInt(s1);
                            int n2 = Integer.parseInt(s2);
                            int n3 = Integer.parseInt(s3);
                            if (good(n0) && good(n1) && good(n2) && good(n3)) {
                                System.out.println(n0 + "." + n1 + "." + n2 + "." + n3);

                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }
}

private boolean good(String s) {
    // Not allowed to remove leading zeros.
    return s.length() == 1 || s.charAt(0) != '0';
}

private boolean good(int n) {
    // Between 0 and 255
    return n >= 0 && n <= 255;
}
```

which prints

```
19.216.80.1.
192.16.80.1.
192.168.0.1.
```

Comment: Forth for loop is not necesey you can change it to `int d=number.length() - a - b -c`

Comment: @talex - You are correct - and if we were looking for the most efficient method I wouldn't do it this way at all - but this code is clear and obvious, my primary aim when optimal is not critical.

Comment: in this case you solution look great. only problem that `192.16.8.1` is wrong for `19216801` you loose `0`

Comment: @talex - Perhaps! But what should be output for "192168000001"?

Comment: I think this input illegal, but better ask Jack

Comment: That is wrong as 192.16.8.1. (with the tailing dot) is not a valid format of ip address